# How to center my "inputPane" using JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, layout, borderpane

How can I center my panel `inputPane` in a `BorderPane`, in JavaFX?

Here's my code.

```
public class MainStage {
    private Scene mainScene;
    private InputPane inputPane;
    private DisplayPane displayPane;
    private EditPane editPane;
    private BorderPane borderPane;

    private VBox mainPane;

    public MainStage(){
        borderPane = new BorderPane();
        inputPane=new InputPane();
        displayPane=new DisplayPane();
        editPane=new EditPane();


        mainPane=new VBox();
        mainPane.getChildren().addAll(inputPane.getPane(),displayPane.getTable(),editPane.getPane());
        mainPane.setSpacing(10);

        mainScene=new Scene(mainPane,800,480);
        mainScene.getStylesheets().add("styleSheet.css");
    }
    public Scene getMainScene() {
        return mainScene;
    }
    public InputPane getInputPane() {
        return inputPane;
    }
    public DisplayPane getDisplayPane() {
        return displayPane;
    }
    public EditPane getEditPane(){
        return editPane;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to modify `InputPane` class.

```
public class InputPane {

    private Text server;
    private Text textNumber;
    private TextField tfNumber;

    private Button addButton;
    private GridPane griglia;

    public InputPane() {

        textNumber=new Text("Insert Port Number: ");
        server = new Text("SERVER");
        server.setStyle("-fx-font-weight:bold;"
                       +"-fx-color: black;"
                       +"-fx-font-size: 18;");
        tfNumber = new TextField();
        tfNumber.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(new NumberStringConverter()));

        griglia=new GridPane();

        griglia.add(server,1,0);
        griglia.add(textNumber,0,1);
        griglia.add(tfNumber,1,1);
        griglia.setVgap(5);
        griglia.setHgap(10);

        GridPane.setHalignment(server, HPos.CENTER);
        GridPane.setHalignment(textNumber, HPos.CENTER);

    }

    public GridPane getPane() {
        return griglia;
    }
    public Button getAddButton() {
        return addButton;
    }
}
```

I give you some ideas of how you can see now my GUI:

This is the result
[image: This is the result]

And I would like to make somethink like this
[image: And I would like to make somethink like this]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not really clear as you ask :

> How can I center my panel inputPane in a BorderPane, in JavaFX?

But in your example, you never use your `BorderPane`, you only use `VBox`

To answer to your question, simply use an `HBox` as parent of your `GridPane` with alignment property set to `Pos.CENTER`.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane bord = new BorderPane();
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        GridPane griglia = new GridPane();
        Text server = new Text("SERVER");
        griglia.add(server, 1, 0);
        griglia.add(new Text("Numero Porta"), 0, 1);
        griglia.add(new TextField(), 1, 1);
        griglia.setVgap(5.0);
        griglia.setHgap(5.0);
        GridPane.setValignment(server, VPos.CENTER);
        GridPane.setHalignment(server, HPos.CENTER);
        hb.getChildren().add(griglia);
        hb.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red");
        hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        bord.setTop(hb);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(bord, 800, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: My main idea were to create a VBox to add in the top the input of the app (centered, this is the reason why I "used" a GridPane inside a BordedPane), in the center the list, that I will catch from a List that I made in a different class, and at the bottom the Button to continue.
But now I've tried your code, and it's exactly what i was looking for.
Thank you a lot.